# Facebook dynamic og:image using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a PHP site which needs multiple Facebook sharing images (og:image) and I'm parsing the URL and echoing the relevant filename into the og:image meta tag.

Viewing the page source shows it has the correct image, but Facebook debugger still scrapes the primary (home page) og:image.

`<meta property="og:image" content="site.net/img/meta/<?php echo $og_image ?>.jpg">`

Is there a way to have the shared og:image change relative to the full URL?

i.e. I share `site.net/home` and Facebook grabs one image while `site.net/about` would share another og:image.

Comment: Sure, just output one or the other, and make sure you're not setting `og:url` to the home page on the pages with custom images.

Comment: Would it make sense to output an $og_url also and make both og:url and og:image dynamic?

Comment: You can. You can also leave `og:url` off entirely - Facebook will use the URL of the page as a fallback. It's only really *necessary* if you want to canonicalize multiple possible URLs for the same page, like `example.com/about` and `example.com/about.html`.

Comment: Sweet, thanks. Put that in an answer and I'll accept it and you can get the mileage points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have a unique `og:image` (and any of the other Open Graph tags) on a per-page basis - just output different OG tags on those pages.

The most common reason these don't take is having an `og:url` page that points somewhere else (like the root at `example.com`), as Facebook will consider that the "canonical" URL for the page and fetch the OG tags from *there* instead of the current URL. You can set a unique `og:url` for each page, or you can leave it off entirely - if it's missing, Facebook will use the current URL as a fallback.